# Python Regex Passive Groups and Lookbehind

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
# print thestring
abcd\t$500\n
```

I want to extract the dollar value of 500 without the dollar sign.

Here is my code:

```
# trying positive lookbehind
m = re.search('(<=\$)\d+$',thestring)
# trying passive groups
m = re.search('(?:\$)\d+$',thestring)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-capturing groups do not remove the result from the matched substring, so that's why the second solution didn't work. The first solution should work, but you seem to have mistyped the syntax for a positive lookbehind. It should be:

```
(?<=\$)\d+$
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of non-capturing groups?

Comment: @Abdulla a non capturing group, groups the content together, but is not storing the result. Its faster than a capturing group. Use capturing groups only if you need to reuse the content of this group.

Comment: They are also useful if you need to modify the regex in a way that requires grouping, but don't want to affect the numbering of existing groups.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should either escape your backslashes or use raw strings:

```
'(<=\\$)\\d+$'
```

or

```
r'(<=\$)\d+$'
```

Next, why use the lookbehind or the passive group? You want to capture the number, right? How about:

```
m = re.search('\\$(\\d+)',thestring)
```

Then retrieve your number using `m.group(1)`.

Comment: Why should there be two backslashes? It seems to work fine with one. Sorry, I'm very new to regex.

Comment: Yes, because you're lucky and neither '\$' nor '\d' are valid escape sequences. But if you typed, say '\n' you would get a single newline character, instead of a slash and an 'n'. - In your interactive python shell, evaluate one of your unescaped strings. The interpreter will return it in an escaped fashion.

Comment: `\n` isn't actually a problem because that escape sequence translates to a Python newline just fine. `\b` is a better example - as a regex, it means "word boundary", in a string, it means "backspace".

Comment: For more details, see the [reference documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals).